# Cannot Find Place ID

Tags: web-services, google-places-api

I see that others have asked this question, but I haven't seen any 'how-to' answers for businesses that can't find their Place ID.

When I type my business name and address into the place id finder it does not return any results.

My business on google maps: https://www.google.com/maps/place/Fancy+Fox/@41.6057788,-93.8500368,11z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1sfancy+fox+des+moines!3m4!1s0x87ec24217b23e6fb:0x3cbf2ea78697e2ff!8m2!3d41.5973725!4d-93.701036?hl=en

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you should be aware of:

- Once you added your business in Google My Business you have to wait some time (probably up to 7 days) while the business will be available in the place autocomplete service.
- If you created a Service Area Business, it probably won't appear in place autocomplete due to the following issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35831063

As I can see, you have indeed created a Service Area Business, it has a polygon on maps.google.com. I would suggest reaching out directly to Google support in the [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:188875&p=1) and ask them to help get a place ID.

**UPDATE**

As of March 2018 you can now search all businesses place IDs using the Google My Business place ID finder:

https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/faq#how-to-find-placeid

Comment: I was wondering if my issue was related to my 'service area' choice. Thank you for providing the Google support link.

Answer (score 0):

Try GMB Toolbox to decode your location to a Place ID http://gmb.reviewsmaker.com

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: There is an issue, the suggested tool doesn't work with Service Area Businesses. Try to find the business mentioned by author of this question.